# PostgreSQL: How to replace different value in the same field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have here a super uncleaned data (i must admit it -_-)

Field: **Amount** which is **char**

```
Values are '20 35' & '25..56'
```

How can i sum this with these two different value?

I can't used

```
 cast(replace("Amount",' ','.')  as DECIMAL)
```

since it only applied in **Amount** with space.

Already correct the datatype of its field.

Please help me. TIA! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to replace non-digits with a decimal point:

```
select cast(regexp_replace('25sd  ss343', '[^\d]+', '.', 'g') as decimal)
```

Comment: Thanks for this help, but it become whole number. from 25..56 it became 2556.. The result should be 25.56  :)